# How do I set up derby in eclipse on Ubuntu?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-9.10, derby, javadb

The question basically says it all.  I'm trying setup up JavaDB on my virtualbox running Ubuntu 9.10.
I have the package downloaded and installed through the package manager, which I believe is the right to go about it. I have also installed the Eclipse's Data Platform Tools. I've been following this tutorial here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDataToolsPlatform/article.html.
I'm stuck at the driver definition step.  When I select the driver template from the Name/Type tab and the jar file in the Jar List tab, the OK button is never enabled.  At the top of the New Driver Definition dialog it says 'Unable to locate Jar/zip in the file system as specified by the driver definition: derby.jar.'  I assume this is the problem.  Any help or links to a better tutorial would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my problem was that I had forgotten to initially install derby as an eclipse plugin.  I should have thought of this earlier, but Apache actually has a good tutorial for installing derby, integrating it with eclipse and building a sample project.

The link is here: http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/derby_plugin.html.

Comment: No plug-ins anymore: "Between version 10.3 and 10.8.2, Apache Derby distributions included plug-ins for Eclipse." http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/derby_plugin_info.html

Answer (score 0):

- Download the latest Derby version from the Apache website http://db.apache.org/derby/. Choose the binary distribution. Unzip the file to the Eclipse installation directory. The zip file will unpack to create a new subdirectory under the plugins directory of the Eclipse installation.
  Source: http://db.apache.org/derby/integrate/derby_plugin.html#Install
- You can also  add a folder "lib" to your project then copy the file derby.jar from your Derby download into this folder.
  Derby tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDataToolsPlatform/article.html